# Haskell sorting of an unorderable list using a proxy order

Tags: haskell, sorting

Suppose I have `x :: [(n, a)]` where n is a number and a is an unorderable item (is not of class Ord).

I want to sort this list by n.

I cannot do `sort x` because `a` is not orderable. I can replace `a` by indices and then assemble the new list using `!!` but this seems like a poor solution.

Alternatives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ugh. Never mind. `sortBy`.

Comment: not just `sortBy` but `sortBy (comparing fst)`  (in case you never heard of the `comparing` function).

Comment: `comparing` is in `Data.Ord`. (But you knew that, because you used hoogle.)

Comment: [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle)?  Cool, I always just asked Neil Mitchell every time I needed to know where a function was...

Answer (score 5):

You want

```
sortBy (compare `on` fst)
```

or something similar.
You'll find `on` defined in module `Data.Function`, and `sortBy` in `Data.List`, which you'll need to import.

Comment: Just as a follow up, the more conventional usage is to take advantage of the definition:

    comparing = on compare

Not to contradict the vastly better-skilled Dr. Ramsey, just pointing out a more usual style.

Comment: @BMpeh don't give me more credit than I'm worth.  I learned `on compare` from somebody else and am happy to learn `comparing` from you.  (Leaving answer unchanged lest readers become hopelessly confused.)

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have an alternate function (e.g., call it `f`) from which to form an order, you can use the Data.Monoid properties of Ordering:

```
sortBy (comparing fst `mappend` comparing (f . snd))
```

which will use your function on the second component of the pair. If you don't need or have a second criterion on which to sort your pairs, then the `sortBy (comparing fst)` will be just fine (the resulting list will just have pairs with the same first component in list order).